# git bash asking for passphrase when nothing set

Tags: git, bash, ssh, bitbucket

I am trying to connect to make an initial push to my bitbucket account, my .ssh/config looks like this:

```
Host bitbucket.org
  Hostname bitbucket.org
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/test.ppk
```

but when I run the command:

```
git push -u origin master
```

I get prompted for my ssh passphrase:

```
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/UserName/.ssh/test.ppk':
```

I tried using a key with a passphrase and entering it here, and then tried again using a key without a passphrase. No matter what I get this error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

-my repository does exist and the public key is loaded into the bitbucket account. as well I have read and write permissions to the repo.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/test.ppk
```

I guess this key was generated by putty? OpenSSH doesn't read putty format key files. The putty key generator program has an option to export key files in the OpenSSH format.

```
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/UserName/.ssh/test.ppk':
```

OpenSSH (at least some versions) will ask for a passphrase any time it can't parse the key file. It doesn't matter if the key file is in a format that OpenSSH recognizes:

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=randokey bs=1024 count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1024 bytes transferred in 0.000094 secs (10900932 bytes/sec)
$ chmod 600 randokey
$ ssh -i randokey localhost
Enter passphrase for key 'randokey':
```